# How to rename all .jpg files in all subdirs wich contains dash in linux?

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename

I have subfolders with dashes (example subdir with name c-d). I need to rename all .jpg files in all subdirs. Any tips how to do it? I've tried many options, but nothing helped (I think because my subfolders contains dashes -) Thanks guys! :)

I have tried

```
find -name '*.jpg' -exec rename $RANDOM.jpg $RANDOM.jpg {} \;
```

but getting

```
(Missing operator before jpg?) syntax error at (user-supplied code)
line 3, near "2635.jpg" Bareword found where operator expected at
(eval 4) line 1, near "#line 1 2635.jpg"
```

Comment: What exactly is the intent of `$RANDOM.jpg $RANDOM.jpg`?  `rename` expects a valid Perl expression telling it what to rename the files *from* and *to*

Comment: I don't know because i've found it in the web. So how i can rename to a random name all .jpg files in all subdirs? Thanks for your answer,  steeldriver

Comment: Are you sure you want to rename all your Jpegs to something like `XrUg2oCLIIoBGwH.jpg`, `l9OD0lus8Ft1LJ9.jpg`, and `73k9qXms3rIH2Mr.jpg`? I'm looking forward to reading a question about getting rid of files with weird names then.

Comment: Yes, new random name can be whatever name. Thanks! :)

Comment: Here is the command which i used to rename files for i in *.jpg; do mv $i $RANDOM$RANDOM.jpg; done
But how to tell mv to rename jpg's in all subdirs?

Comment: Maybe the sybtax of the find should be `find -name '*.jpg' -exec rename {} $RANDOM.jpg  \; `  That will rename each .jpg file found (`{}`) to the content of $RANDOM with .jpg added.

Comment: @SorenA That will rename all files to the same name because `$RANDOM` gets evaluated only once.

Comment: @PerlDuck  ..  ups.

Comment: You should try `find -name '*.jpg' -exec echo rename $RANDOM.jpg $RANDOM.jpg {} \;` to see, what would happen, and then test SorenAs advice, which might work. However, maybe rename misreads a dash for an option. Often programs allow for such cases an -- as END_OF_OPTIONS-mark. Read `rename --help` and  `man rename` to investigate this. And to include PerlDucks advice, we need a script for find, don't we? `find -name '*.jpg' -exec bash -c 'rename -n {} "$RANDOM.jpg" \; `

Answer (score 2):

There is no case for rename, because you may just do it with mv.

```
find -name '*.jpg' -exec bash -c 'mv -i "{}" "$RANDOM.jpg"' \;
```

mv -i means interactive. It asks before overwriting.

This is not testet in depth, just ad hoc, to make sure files will get different names. A little more testing would be:

```
find -name '*.jpg' -exec echo bash -c 'mv -i "{}" "$RANDOM.jpg"' \;
```

However, this will put all files to the current dir. Maybe using -execdir is an option?

```
find -name '*.jpg' -execdir bash -c 'mv -i "{}" "$RANDOM.jpg"' \;
```

However, make a backup, be careful about your data and so on. Mass actions with find are a sharp instrument. I take no responsibility.

AFAIK dashes have no horses in this race.

Comment: Especially the third one is perfect, but the purpose of this whole thing is still obscure. To me, at least.

Comment: This is the right approach IMHO except that you might consider `bash -c 'for f; do mv -i -- "$f" "$RANDOM.jpg"; done' bash {} +` (for efficiency, and to avoid expansion of the `{}` inside the command string). The OP could also consider using something like `"$(mktemp --suffix=.jpg --tmpdir=. XXXXXX)"` in place of `$RANDOM` since the latter is not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Did you test for efficiency? What did you get? IMHO, this action will be harddrive limited, so trying to read and write at the same time might end up in worse performance. It's an additional layer of complexity, and I've learned to just do it right, and later care for performance, and only, if necessary. But I'm very interested in numbers, so if you have made some measurements, be invited! Because I hear such advice often, in connection with find ";" and +.

Answer (score 0):

You're unclear about *how* you want files to renamed. As far as *which* files to rename you can use `find` to match all files according you the desired pattern containing a dash:

```sh
find [PATH...] -type f -name '*-*' | prename EXPR
```

If you want to match directories too you need to use the `-depth` option:

```sh
find [PATH...] -depth -name '*-*' | prename EXPR
```

Comment: I think the OP is *mistakenly* attributing the `rename` error to the fact that their *directories* have dashes in their names

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on sub-folders with a dash in their name, and it worked.

### Renaming Portions of Filenames Recusively in Linux/Ubuntu

To rename files, you use the **find** command in conjunction with the **rename** command like this:

```
find -type f -execdir rename 's/OriginalText/NewText/' *.jpg '{}' \;
```

So if you want to replace all the dashes "-" in all the jpg filenames with underscores "_" then you would enter:

```
find -type f -execdir rename 's/-/_/' *.jpg '{}' \;
```